# Trying to create a table, but it comes up with this error

Tags: oracle

I am new to mysql and I can't really figure out as to why I keep on getting the  missing right parenthesis error from this code:

```
/*second oracle program */
/*Franklin Tong */

set echo on 

spool c:hw3.text

drop table student;

create table student(
    snn char(9),
    lastname char(10),
    firstname char(10),
    major char(10),
    GPA number(3,2)
    DOB date
    );
insert into student (111,Smith,Johnny,IS,3.41,5/18/82);
insert into student (102,Smith,Jack,FIN,3.25,3/11/80);

select * from student;

spool off
```

system returns a message saying:
error at line 7
ora-00907: missing right parathesis

Comment: If you're getting an `ORA-00907`, then you're not connected to a MySQL database but an Oracle RDBMS. Those are completely different beasts, don't confuse them.

Comment: Unrelated but: you moste definitely do **not** want `char` for any of your columns. In addition to the missing comma, please also read the manual for the correct syntax of the [insert statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604) (pay attention to the part that comes after table name) and the correct way to [specify a string literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a comma ',' after 'GPA number(3,2)'.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ',' after 'GPA number(3,2)'.